# find column/row value, sum values in another column on rows after, until next row value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am have thousands of sheets in a workbook that are formatted in such a way that I am unable to run simple code to query.

For every sheet I need to:
Sum the total usage value across all sheets for a classification number found in column D, however all the values are in rows beneath that column value, and in another column.
e.g.

- Find classification in Column D
- Sum all rows that follow in column I until the
  next value in Column D **OR**
- Find next occurrence of "Usage" in column H and return the adjacent value in column I

Summary sheet has a list of all valid classification values possible in Column D, and I want the Usage $ against them.

Any help much appreciated - example data below with highlighted values:

```
    208      Contract Administrator                                         
G   7405     1.          569.05     0.00    0.00        0.00        3533        
G   7130     1.          1,275.35   0.00    0.00        0.00        5806        
             Usage       1,844.40   0.00    0.00        0.00                
             Sales       0.00       0.00    0.00        0.00                
    210      Council Fee                                            
G   7127     1.          412.50     0.00    0.00        0.00        5034        
G   7127    -1.         -412.50     0.00    0.00        0.00        5807        
             Usage       0.00       0.00    0.00        0.00                
             Sales       0.00       0.00    0.00        0.00
```

Comment: What have you tried? If the data is always laid out in the same way for everything, then you can just sum with references to the various books. Otherwise, you'll need to possibly use VBa

Comment: The part that gets me is the 1,000s of sheets in one workbook. Seems like you need a report/query that gets all of the data in one sheet, then creating a summary sheet would be a lot easier.

Comment: @Dave unfortunately it is not laid out the same way, there can be hundred of lines under each header, and each $$ value needs to have the "208" header for example next to it to do simple lookups.  Am looking for a VBA solution.

Comment: @gns100 thanks, I wish that was an option but currently it is not.  The export is a heavily customised .xls that was created back in 2009 when the software was first installed.

Comment: Then my advice is learn VBa

Comment: Only other thought is try powerQuery (excel 2016 is Data -> get and transform section). But not sure how it'll handle 1,000s sheets...